# Anor Londo : Sliver knight Spear

Tags: dark-souls

I currently finished my stay at Anor Londo defeating **Dragon Slayer Ornstein & Executioner Smough** (Shhh... Finally). And am headed towards defeating the Ceaseless Discharge.

I am currently at level 60 and have accidentally killed The Blacksmith : Andre of Astora. I have moved on with my gameplay ignoring the fact that i could no longer upgrade my weapons anymore beside from fire augmentation upgrade provided by Blacksmith Vamos and other possible upgrade by using Weapon SmithBox.

So , I am currently equipped with Sliver Knight Sword +5 and Lightning Spear +5. I am used to these weapons and bit excited with the Spear. After searching for while i found that the Anor Londo Silver Knight drops the ultimate Silver Knight Spear. So ,  i wrapped towards the Anor Londo and begin the hunt for the Spear killing every Silver Knight on Sight.

[image]
**Unfortunately they only drops sword and shield.**

Question :

1. Where else can i find it ?
2. Are there any better Spears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any spear wielding Silver Knight has the *chance* to drop the Silver Knight Spear, you just have to farm it a little bit.

As for a *better* spear, there are some that can be traded in for boss souls that have special effects;

- Dragonslayer spear: 2-hand R2 shoots a bolt of lightning, and is lightning imbued.
- Moonlight Butterfly Horn: This is similar to the Moonlight Sword, in that it only deals magic damage, and no physical.

Another spear of mention Is the Channeler's trident, the 2-handed R2 gives a AOE STR buff to the wielder and nearby friendlies.

Other than that, it's hard to answer your question further without stats, and it also depends on your play style.

Comment: That's the real issue here. I kept farming hoping for Spear and all i got is sword and the shield. About my stat i am A Dex player with Dex level 25 , Strength 19 and Vitality 24.

Comment: I think you might have something confused. Are you looking for the spear or have you already found it?

Comment: My mistake  * shield

Comment: I know for a fact that the Spear-wielding silver knights *do drop the spear*, just have to keep trying. You'll get it eventually

Comment: Also for a Dex build, the best spear is probably that Dragonslayer spear, it has a B scaling in Dex, and a C scaling in STR and Faith as well.

Comment: Little curious though ain't `Channeler's trident` available in Dark Souls 2 as well.

Comment: Yes it is. A lot of weapons have been carried over to DkS2, including the Demon's Greathammer and the Dragonslayer spear as well.

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting the spear if you have higher item discovery. Grab the covetous gold serpent ring, pop some humanity (no need to reverse hollowing and 10 gives you the max discovery bonus) and you should get a drop pretty soon after.

Comment: @slow_excellence That's pretty much my answer ;D

Comment: @dominic de coco - Ahh sorry, I was having a pretty spotty connection to the internet and the phone client is kinda crappy lol.

Answer (score 2):

Silver Knight Swords only drop from sword wielding knights, while the Spear **only** drops from **spear wielding** [Silver Knights](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/silver-knight). When you get a lot of swords, you seem to be killing the wrong knights.

The fastest way to farm spears is at the second bonfire in Anor Londo (the room with Solaire sitting at the bonfire, after evading greatarrows on a narrow ledge). There is a spear wielding knight only a few steps from the bonfire in the opposite room.

Try to hold 10 humanity and equip the [Covetous Gold Serpent Ring](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/covetous-gold-serpent-ring) from Sen's Fortress to maximise your item discovery rate. You should hold at least 1 humanity if having 10 is too much of a risk for you, because the additional drop chance decreases by each additional humanity. Doing both greatly increases the drop chance for the Silver Knight Spear, but it's still a rather uncommon drop. But then again the swords are an uncommon drop as well, and you seemed to have luck with them.

Comment: Yes exactly that's the issue ... in the bonfire floor there are four Knights .. i presume 3 Spear and 1 Sword Knights. And i am equipped with "Covetous Gold Serpent Ring : Boosts Item Discovery" , And the Spear ones seems to only drop Shields.

Comment: P.S I like being `Undead` and only time i have to be `human` , is to kindle bonfire.

Comment: @Runcorn Seems like that's just bad luck then. The shield has the same drop rate as far as I know, so if you keep going you will get the spear eventually. Whether you're undead or human doesn't affect the drop rate. You should just keep active humanity. The ring increases the drop chance by 200 and the first humanity by 50. If you have 10 humanity (undead or human) and the ring you'll have a discovery rate of 610 instead of 100, which is the maximum item discovery rate. You can check yours in the character stats, if you didn't know this already.

Comment: Thanks i will try it out today and let you know how good is my luck. Thanks.